# How to start the local neo4j server on Windows using PowerShell script?

Tags: java, powershell, neo4j

I have downloaded the zip folder of neo4j community edition version-2.3.1 in order to start connecting the neo4j server through Java code. I want to create graph database for indexing of the data. Followed [this link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/neo4j/neo4j_zip_environment_setup.htm) originally.

**PROBLEMS**

1. I'm unable to start the neo4j server as the batch file is deprecated and it displays the following message:
   [image]
2. Tried using the PowerShell scripts commands also with reference to [this link](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.3.0-M03/powershell.html), it just opens the script file. the server is not started with these commands.

Where I am going wrong and what is the right procedure to start the local neo4j server and connect it through Java code to create nodes and relationships of the graph.

Comment: The reference looks straight away. You should import PowerShell module and then you can manage neo4j server with imported cmdlets.

Please explain your actions and which step fails for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The batch file will still work even though it has been deprecated. It appears that the batch file cannot find the Findstr command.

`findstr.exe` should be in `%windir%\system32\`

If it is there and you are getting the `findstr` is not recognized as an internal or external command” error, check that `%windir%\system32\` is in your PATH.

Once that works, try the **Neo4j.bat** file again.

And as Anton mentioned, please explain how the Powershell didn't work and what actions you took.